# Display small html snippet in a bounded area

Tags: html, iframe, canvas, thumbnails

I'm looking to visualize a results page and a number of the results I plan on showing have small snippets of html associated with them. Ideally I would like to just put this text inside of an iframe and just be able to set the scale/cropping of the images to make sure that the displayed portion is relevant and intuitive.

Right now what I'm going is using `xhtml2pdf` and `wand` to convert the html to a pdf and then to a jpg, which is nonideal for a number of reasons. I tried just inserting the html directly into the page, but this seemed to be a poor idea for a number of reasons (primarily security as these html snippets are written by other people, secondarily because they were not contained)

Any way though to take a snippet of html and display it in a confined area would be wonderful though. My first thoughts for the task were either canvas or an iframe, but I haven't been able to find anything on whether or not there's a way to do this with those. I'm also not sure if this would be an issue, but I would like to have the relevant css classes applied to the html inside of the display box, but that's just icing on the cake.

I'm pulling the html from a Mongo Instance where the html is one of the fields, so an example of one of the object would be:

```
{ 'ObjectId': 'asdlkc2814s',
    "code": "<p style="font-size:100">This is a sample of the data</p>"
}
```

And what I would like to do is render that html snippet in a bounded box (think thumbnail). I need to be able to specify the size of the thumbnail, but past that I'm not too picky.

Comment: If you for some reason are attached to those html snippets there are not many good options, otherwise if I where you I would go back to the raw data that was provided for the result page and visualize them directly to a canvas. It's a bit abstract what you try to visualize as there is no code/example showing what you try to achieve. :-)

Comment: The raw data is html :( I'm trying to make results for somebody's poorly built database. I'll try adding an example.